# chaining siblings().hide() not working in jqueryui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following:

```
$('.popoutlink').on('click', function() {
   var box = $('#' + $(this).data('box'));
   // box.siblings().hide();
   box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500).siblings().hide(100);
});
```

When I run that the hide doesn't happen.  If I uncomment the commented line and explicitly run the `siblings().hide()` then it works, but chaining it to the toggle method fails.

The HTML is

```
<div class="col-md-6 bb">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p1">1</div>
              <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p2">2</div>
              <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p3">3</div>
              <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p4">4</div>
              <div class="popoutlink" data-box="p5">5</div>
          </div>


            <div class="col-md-10 bb" style="height: 400px;">
              <div class="popout" id="p1">panel 1</div>
              <div class="popout" id="p2">

              </div>
              <div class="popout" id="p3">panel 3</div>
              <div class="popout" id="p4">panel 4</div>
              <div class="popout" id="p5">
                <div id="progressbar"></div>   
                <button id="regress">click me</button>
                <button id="progress">click me</button>
              </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

What's confusing me is I've used this before:

```
$('#trainClick').click(function() {
    $('#train').toggle(1000).siblings().hide(500);
});
```

And it's worked. If I change the code in the original function to:

```
box.toggle(500).siblings().hide(100);
```

then all is well.

I've tried breaking it down to just the slide, then console logging **this**, and **this** is set to the calling div, so it's not a question of **this** being reassigned.

So why is the slide breaking the chain?

Comment: Can you provide us with the relevant HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQueryUI's `toggle` creates a wrapper around the original element. Since the wrapper only contains one element, calling `siblings` on the original element (now that it's inside the wrapper) will return an empty collection.

Use `.parent()` to get the wrapper, and then `.siblings()`:

```
box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500)
   .parent(".ui-effects-wrapper")
   .siblings()
   .hide(100);
```

**NOTE:** This wrapper is part of the effects library internals, so be aware that nothing prevents it changing in later versions. The proper, readable way to do this is without the chain; obtaining the siblings collection before the `.toggle` call:

```
var sib = box.siblings();
box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
sib.hide(100);
```

Comment: and that worked.  I'm left with a weird little bug that if I click on two buttons in rapid succession their related view divs both appear on the screen, but for now that is progress.

Answer (score 0):

For this line to work:

```
 box.toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500).siblings().hide(100);
```

You need to have ***jQuery-UI*** library to be added in the page. The toggle method with slide and direction is not available in the jQuery only.

[Get a demo here.](https://jqueryui.com/toggle/)

Comment: my mistake, should have said, jqueryui is installed and working.